# Dropdown event firing unnecessarily in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dropdowns say ddl1 and ddl2 and a gridview in my aspx page say Home.aspx.

```
  protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtFeedFiles;
        try
        {
            ddl2.DataSource = dtFeedFiles;
            ddl2.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Errorpage"]);
        }
     }

    protected void ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtFeed;
        try
        {
           gridview.DataSource = dtFeed;
           gridview.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Errorpage"]);
        }
     }
```

In the ddl1_selectedIndexChanged event I am loading ddl2.In the ddl2_selectedIndexChanged event I am loading a grid.

An error occured in  ddl2_selectedIndexChanged event and I am redirecting it to an Errorpage.aspx.

Now when I click browser back button it comes to Home.aspx and when I change dll1 both ddl1_selectedIndexChanged ,ddl2_selectedIndexChanged events are firing. Why is it happening so?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the record source for `ddl2` in the `ddl1`'s event, it will trigger a `SelectedIndexChanged` event. This is by design, as if you *had* something selected in `ddl2`, that selection would have been wiped out.

Usually you'll need to have a guard clause such as

```
if (ddl2.SelectedIndex < 0)
{
   // return the gridview to an uninitialized state?
   return;
}
```

in order to prevent the event from continuing execution if an index has not actually been selected for any drop down list.

Comment: Ya.i agree with u..But it doesnot happen while loading the page normally.it happens only when i return to the normal page from an error page.Wy its happening so

Comment: I would guess when you return from the error page, the page attempts to reset the state of the control to where it was before the error, which invalidates a built in guard clause, but honestly I have no idea.